# Como alternar imagens ao clicar em um checkbox?

Tags: html, css

Nesse meu script estou fazendo um marcador de assentos, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que alterne as imagens após o `click` no `checkbox`, e toda hora as cadeiras da mesa ficam desalinhadas.

Tipo:

- checkbox marcado mostra a cadeirinha vermelha
- checkbox desmarcado mostra a cadeirinha vermelha

Como posso fazer isso funcionar?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código: https://jsfiddle.net/fabioo7/9zhgykr5/

```
<div style="width: 700px; height: 850px;  position: absolute; left: -20px;" >



 <div class="imagens" style="position:  static; left: 90px; top: 70px; width: 130px; height: 129px; "  >
<div style="position:  absolute; left: 55px; ">
<div style="position: relative; left: 29px;  top: 38px;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ww2xT7t.png" /></div>

<div style="position: relative; left: 7px;   top: -65px;">
 <input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i1" />
 <label for="i1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/OpIgi4H.png" /></label>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 50px;  top: -155px;">
 <input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i2" />
 <label for="i2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8Iyy2C4.png" /></label>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 95px; top: -188px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i3" />
<label for="i3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M6hK389.png" /></label>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; left: 95px; top: -185px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i4" />
<label for="i4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M5UHtdt.png" /></label>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; left: 49px;  top: -215px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i5" />
<label for="i5"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XWX98Fc.png" /></div></label>


<div style="position: relative; left:  5px;   top: -290px;">
<input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i6" />
<label for="i6"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cdasBJA.png" /></div></label>
</div>



</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No caso do checkbox marcado mostra a cadeira vermelha, e desmarcado verde?

Comment: As duas últimas `divs` estão fechando antes do `label`...

Comment: sim isso... marcado vermelho e desmarcado verde

Comment: Acho que você pode fazer isso se forem imagens em svg. Veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/mudar-cor-do-svg-no-hover) uma pergunta relacionada. E não tenho certeza, mas  acho que trocar a imagem não dá pra fazer com CSS. Não pode ser com JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Técnica de troca de imagem usando CSS puro:

Eis um exemplo simples, para demonstrar a técnica da troca de imagem de fundo com base no atributo `checked`:

```css
input { visibility: hidden; }
label { display: block; width:36px; height:32px; left:50%; top:50%;
        background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Y0g.png') no-repeat center top; }
input:checked + label { background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHDoy.png'); }
```

```html
Clique na cadeira!
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="c1" />
<label id="l1" for="c1"></label>
```

### Aplicando a técnica em várias mesas numeradas:

Usando CSS transforms, fica um código extremamente enxuto e simples de se manter.

```css
.mesa input { visibility: hidden; }

.mesa {
  position:relative; float:left;
  width:140px; height:140px;
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI8cD.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.mesa label {
  position:absolute; display: block;
  width:36px; height:32px; left:50%; top:50%; margin-left:-18px; margin-top:-16px;
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Y0g.png') no-repeat center top;
}

.mesa input:checked + label {
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHDoy.png') no-repeat center top;
}

.mesa span {
  position:absolute; display:block; left:50%; top:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  font:bold 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.l1 { transform:translateY(-50px) }    
.l2 { transform:rotate( 60deg) translateY(-50px) }
.l3 { transform:rotate(120deg) translateY(-50px) }
.l4 { transform:rotate(180deg) translateY(-50px) }
.l5 { transform:rotate(240deg) translateY(-50px) }
.l6 { transform:rotate(300deg) translateY(-50px) }
```

```html
Clique nas cadeiras.<br>
<div class="mesa">
  <span>1</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m11" name="m1" value="1"><label class="l1" for="m11"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m12" name="m1" value="2"><label class="l2" for="m12"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m13" name="m1" value="3"><label class="l3" for="m13"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m14" name="m1" value="4"><label class="l4" for="m14"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m15" name="m1" value="5"><label class="l5" for="m15"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m16" name="m1" value="6"><label class="l6" for="m16"></label>
</div>
<div class="mesa">
  <span>2</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m21" name="m2" value="1"><label class="l1" for="m21"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m22" name="m2" value="2"><label class="l2" for="m22"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m23" name="m2" value="3"><label class="l3" for="m23"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m24" name="m2" value="4"><label class="l4" for="m24"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m25" name="m2" value="5"><label class="l5" for="m25"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m26" name="m2" value="6"><label class="l6" for="m26"></label>
</div>
<div class="mesa">
  <span>3</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m31" name="m3" value="1"><label class="l1" for="m31"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m32" name="m3" value="2"><label class="l2" for="m32"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m33" name="m3" value="3"><label class="l3" for="m33"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m34" name="m3" value="4"><label class="l4" for="m34"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m35" name="m3" value="5"><label class="l5" for="m35"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m36" name="m3" value="6"><label class="l6" for="m36"></label>
</div>
```

Com isto, fica fácil o reaproveitamento do mesmo CSS para quantas mesas quiser. Ao se gerar mesas *server-side*, duplica-se apenas o HTML.

**Para *browsers* um pouco mais velhos esta técnica também funciona.** Basta trocar os `transform`s por posição absoluta, e imagens separadas para as cadeiras (ou melhor ainda, um *sprite* com todas as imagens e a mesa).

O importante é usar a imagem como fundo, pois assim dá pra trocar sem JS.

### Update: mesas de 4 e 6 cadeiras:

Segue um exemplo da versatilidade do código. Com três linhas a mais no CSS, e ajuste em mais duas, criamos as classes `.lq1`, `.lq2`, `.lq3`, `.lq4` e '.q', e podemos com isso misturar mesas de 4 e 6 lugares.

Em vez de usar duas mesas diferentes, eu acrescentaria o prato na imagem da cadeira, o que deixaria o código totalmente reaproveitável.

Expanda o exemplo abaixo para ver em funcionamento:

```css
.mesa input { visibility: hidden; }

.mesa {
  position:relative; float:left;
  width:140px; height:140px;
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI8cD.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.q { background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIc21.png') }

.mesa label {
  position:absolute; display: block;
  width:36px; height:32px; left:50%; top:50%; margin-left:-18px; margin-top:-16px;
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Y0g.png') no-repeat center top;
}

.mesa input:checked + label {
  background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHDoy.png') no-repeat center top;
}

.mesa span {
  position:absolute; display:block; left:50%; top:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  font:bold 15px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}



.l1, .lq1 { transform:translateY(-50px) }    
.l2 { transform:rotate( 60deg) translateY(-50px) }
.l3 { transform:rotate(120deg) translateY(-50px) }
.l4, .lq3 { transform:rotate(180deg) translateY(-50px) }
.l5 { transform:rotate(240deg) translateY(-50px) }
.l6 { transform:rotate(300deg) translateY(-50px) }
.lq2 { transform:rotate( 90deg) translateY(-50px) }
.lq4 { transform:rotate(270deg) translateY(-50px) }
```

```html
Clique nas cadeiras.<br>
<div class="mesa">
  <span>1</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m11" name="m1" value="1"><label class="l1" for="m11"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m12" name="m1" value="2"><label class="l2" for="m12"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m13" name="m1" value="3"><label class="l3" for="m13"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m14" name="m1" value="4"><label class="l4" for="m14"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m15" name="m1" value="5"><label class="l5" for="m15"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m16" name="m1" value="6"><label class="l6" for="m16"></label>
</div>
<div class="mesa q">
  <span>2</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m21" name="m2" value="1"><label class="lq1" for="m21"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m22" name="m2" value="2"><label class="lq2" for="m22"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m23" name="m2" value="3"><label class="lq3" for="m23"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m24" name="m2" value="4"><label class="lq4" for="m24"></label>
</div>
<div class="mesa">
  <span>3</span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m31" name="m3" value="1"><label class="l1" for="m31"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m32" name="m3" value="2"><label class="l2" for="m32"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m33" name="m3" value="3"><label class="l3" for="m33"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m34" name="m3" value="4"><label class="l4" for="m34"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m35" name="m3" value="5"><label class="l5" for="m35"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="m36" name="m3" value="6"><label class="l6" for="m36"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Apesar da solução do Samir ser ótima também, a sua é bem simplista, +1

Comment: E mais fácil a manutenção, claro :)

Comment: Concordo com tudo. Sua opção é realmente muito boa, pensei em usar as imagens como bg, mas não dessa maneira. Bastante interessante +1.

Comment: Perfeito seu código.. bem simples de trabalhar, mais uma duvida no outro eu consegui alterar o tipo de mesa em cada bloco e trabalhar com 4 cadeiras.  como eu poderia fazer essa troca no css

Comment: acabei fazendo quase isso que voce falou só que eu repeti a classe do css, agora tem mesa  e mesa4 . valeu obrigado

Comment: to colocando aqui a imagem da mesa de 4 pra quem quiser pegar http://i.imgur.com/EMhWAZP.png

Comment: perfeito ..... ficou 10 agora

Comment: alguns navegadores estão dando erro, as cadeiras estão indo para o centro da mesa.  saberia algum jeito de corrigir isso?

Comment: @FabioHenrique teria que testar individualmente para ver o caso. Mas como eu comentei, lembre que a técnica do CSS serve mesmo no seu modelo antigo (position absolute). Se precisar que funcione em navegadores mais velhos, pode usar as 6 imagens separadas, e o 1º código da resposta. Mas antes, tente usar prefixos no translate pra ver se resolve: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/which-vendor-prefixes-are-needed/ - Aqui tem exemplos: http://shouldiprefix.com/#transforms

Comment: resolvi trocando transform por  -webkit-transform

Comment: @FabioHenrique faça várias linhas, com -ms-, -webkit- etc, assim fica funcional em mais navegadores. E mantenha a linha sem prefixo também.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer isso com essa simples função em javascript, com JQuery:

Se você possuísse uma mesma imagem para todos os labels e somente rotacionasse as imagens, você teria que fazer isso apenas uma vez. Da seguinte maneira

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "imagem-vermelha");
  }else{
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "imagem-verde");
  }
})
```

Infelizmente, no seu atual caso, você deve repetir isso para todos os checkboxes, já que cada `label` possui imagens diferentes.

Usei o método [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) que, basicamente, procura o elemento atencessor, e o método [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/), que procura os elementos filhos mediante o argumento, que no caso foi uma `img`.

Ficaria assim:

```js
    $('#i1').click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://franceimagecoaching.com.br/wp-content/themes/biznex/img/blog-type-article.png");
      }else{
        $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/OpIgi4H.png");
      }
    })
$('#i2').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://franceimagecoaching.com.br/wp-content/themes/biznex/img/blog-type-article.png");
  }else{
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/8Iyy2C4.png");
  }
})
$('#i3').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://franceimagecoaching.com.br/wp-content/themes/biznex/img/blog-type-article.png");
  }else{
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/M6hK389.png");
  }
})
$('#i4').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://franceimagecoaching.com.br/wp-content/themes/biznex/img/blog-type-article.png");
  }else{
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/M5UHtdt.png");
  }
})
$('#i5').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://franceimagecoaching.com.br/wp-content/themes/biznex/img/blog-type-article.png");
  }else{
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/XWX98Fc.png");
  }
})
$('#i6').click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://franceimagecoaching.com.br/wp-content/themes/biznex/img/blog-type-article.png");
  }else{
    $(this).closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/cdasBJA.png");
  }
})
```

```css
    .imagens input[type="checkbox"] {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .imagens label {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid #666;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    .imagens input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label {
      border-color: #ccf;
    }
    
    .imagens img {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 700px; height: 850px;  position: absolute; left: -20px;">

  <div class="imagens" style="position: static; left: 90px; width: 130px; height: 129px; ">

    <div style="position:  absolute; left: 55px; ">
      <div style="position: absolute; left: 29px;  top: 38px;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Ww2xT7t.png" /></div>

      <div style="position: absolute; left: 7px;  top: 2px">
        <input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i1" />
        <label for="i1"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/OpIgi4H.png" /></label>
      </div>

      <div style="position: absolute; left: 50px;  top: -15px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i2" />
        <label for="i2"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8Iyy2C4.png" /></label>
      </div>

      <div style="position: absolute; left: 94px; top: 5px">
        <input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i3" />
        <label for="i3"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M6hK389.png" /></label>
      </div>

      <div style="position: absolute; left: 97px; top: 55px">
        <input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i4" />
        <label for="i4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/M5UHtdt.png" /></label>
      </div>

      <div style="position: absolute; left: 49px;  top: 90px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i5" />
        <label for="i5"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/XWX98Fc.png" /></label>
      </div>

      <div style="position: absolute; left: 3px;  top: 55px">
        <input type="checkbox" name="imagem" id="i6" />
        <label for="i6"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/cdasBJA.png" /></label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

No javascript, em cada checkbox, você teria que colocar cada imagem para quando estivesse marcado e quando estivesse desmarcado.

No seu HTML fiz algumas mudanças, com arrumar os fechamentos de algumas tags e organizei as cedeiras, dando a elas, um `position: absolute` e posicionando-as manualmente.

### UPDATE

Para que a cadeira fique vermelha sem a necessidade do `click`, criei uma função para cada `checkbox`. Por exemplo, a do `#i1`.

```
 $('#i1').click(i1);
 function i1() {
   if ($('#i1').is(":checked")) {
     $('#i1').closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://franceimagecoaching.com.br/wp-content/themes/biznex/img/blog-type-article.png");
   } else {
     $('#i1').closest('div').children('label').children('img').attr("src", "http://i.imgur.com/OpIgi4H.png");
   }
 }
```

E a final do código, chame todas as funções:

```
i1();
i2();
...
i6();
```

[**Exemplo - JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/voo2L4c7/)

Usei uma imagem exemplo já que não tinha cada cadeira vermelha.

Comment: Show isso mesmo... no meu caso serão 30 mesas, então é sou repetir  esses bloco do js e alterar o $('#i6') correspondente

Comment: @FabioHenrique, essas cadeiras são rotacionadas, como o da sua imagem?

Comment: São 30 mesas  fixas  (como assim rotacionadas? )

Comment: Pois caso todas as mesas tenham a mesma imagem, você não precisa repetir até o $('#i6') até o trita, basta fazer um vez, utilizando o primeiro exemplo da minha resposta.

Comment: no primeiro exemplo não funcionou muito bem pra mim aqui, ele é legal por que é um código pequeno

Comment: Isso, não funcionou porque são imagens diferentes, caso  fosse iguais, serviria..... Mas, em suma, a resposta lhe serviu como desejava?

Comment: sim funcionou Obrigado Samir...

Comment: Samir só um probleminha aqui...  se o input já vier "checked" ele continua na cadeirinha verde, como da pra corrigir isso?

Comment: Darei um olhada nisso, quando conseguir aviso

Comment: @FabioHenrique, dê uma olhada JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/voo2L4c7/. Criei uma função para cada checkbox. Explicarei isso na resposta.

Comment: valeu funcionou..