# Mouse Hover não funciona nas células do calendário circular em SVG

Tags: css, svg, css-hover

gostaria de pedir ajuda novamente, estou com dificuldade em fazer funcionar o hover (CSS) sobre o meu SVG. Trata-se de um calendário circular com 31 dias, divididos em três turnos (cada camada é um turno). Ao passar o mouse sobre cada célula, eu gostaria que o fundo trocasse de cor com efeito (transition 2s). Porém o CSS não está funcionando.

Cada célula tem o ID igual **d**xx**s**yy, onde d = dia, e s = turno.
Então por exemplo, para trocar a cor dá célula do dia 15 no segundo turno, seria o id=d15s2 no SVG.

O código completo do SVG segue abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O SVG tem o tamanho muito grande
[SVG do calendario acima](http://%3Ciframe%20src=%22https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/yRJm0E6v%22%20style=%22border:none;width:100%25%22%3E%3C/iframe%3E)

```html
<script src="https://pastebin.com/embed_js/yRJm0E6v"></script>
```

```css
#d1s1 {
    transition: fill 2s;
}

#d1s1:hover {
    fill: #ffff00;
}
```

Enfim, o que eu quero fazer é ao passar o mouse sobre qualquer célula deste calendário circular, o fundo fique de outra cor (amarelo), e ao clicar, ele permanecer em uma dessas cores: verde, vermelho ou cinza.

Comment: Sobre o transition não estar funcionando eu respondi abaixo, sobre trocar a cor no clique essa resposta pode te ajudar, mas com jQuery ou JS vc consegue no evento do clique colocar ou tirar a cor https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286686/mudar-a-cor-de-um-svg-por-um-bot%C3%A3o/286696#286696

Answer (score 3):

Dei uma olhada no código do seu SVG e um dos motivos dele estar GIGANTE é que vc está usando CSS *inline*, direto em cada um dos vetores tipo `style="propriedades"` o correto seria vc criar uma classe e usar nos vetores.

Inclusive esse é o problema com o seu CSS, vc tem que sobrescrever o `fill` que está *inline* na tag, e para isso vc tem que usar um `!important`. Então crie um CSS para todos os `paths` e coloque `!important` no `fill` do `:hover`.

```
<defs>
    <style>
        path {
            transition: fill 2s;
        }
        path:hover {
            fill:red !important;
        }
    </style>
</defs>
```

**OBS 1:** Dessa forma vai funcionar. Apesar disso a forma como o SVG foi gerado está meio comprometida... Quando vc fizer o `:hover` ai vc vai ver que a cor não preenche completamente a célula e isso só tem como corrigir gerando outro SVG...

**OBS 2:** Repare que no estilo eu coloquei o CSS para TODOS os paths do SVG por isso fica um pouco bugado, mas vc deve fazer isso apenas para os `paths` das células, para isso crie uma classe específica e remova o `style=""` direto das tag entende

Como o arquivo é grande fiz um vídeo para vc ver o resultado...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sensacional. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Você não consegue alterar o `fill` via `:hover` no `<style>` porque ele já está definido via *style inline*:

```
<path style="fill:#ffffff;stroke-width:1.95499432"...
```

Para o `:hover` funcionar no `<style>` você deve definir o `fill` no `<style>`, e pode aproveitar também para definir o `stroke-width`, e remova o `style` do elemento:

**Elemento sem style:**

```
<path d="m 409.51823,171.04465 c -1.61287,-0.34827 -8.87078,-1.19599 -16.1287,-1.88382 l -13.19621,-1.2506 v -25.25932 -25.25932 l 10.26372,0.0148 c 9.75768,0.014 34.79672,3.33913 36.27473,4.81715 0.64735,0.64736 -6.48667,38.8851 -8.67303,46.48669 -0.95153,3.30828 -2.31046,3.67973 -8.54051,2.33446 z"
   id="d1s1"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,4.9999997,48.5)"
   inkscape:label="d1s1" />
```

**CSS para o #d1s1:**

```
<style>
#d1s1 {
   fill:#ffffff;
   stroke-width:1.95499432;
   transition: fill 2s;
}

#d1s1:hover {
   fill: #ffff00;
}
</style>
```

O ideal é aplicar aos `path` (já que todos são `path`) e não a cada `id`, logo seria:

```
path {
   fill:#ffffff;
   stroke-width:1.95499432;
   transition: fill 2s;
}

path:hover {
   fill: #ffff00;
}
```

Para alterar a cor no clique, crie classes com as cores e adicione via JavaScript. Por exemplo, crie uma classe para a cor verde:

```
.verde{
   fill: #090;
}
```

Adicione um dataset `cor` com o nome da classe no `path` de acordo com a cor que você deseja para ele ao ser clicado:

```
<path data-cor="verde" d="m 409.51823,171.04465 c -1.61287,-0.34827 -8.87078,-1.19599 -16.1287,-1.88382 l -13.19621,-1.2506 v -25.25932 -25.25932 l 10.26372,0.0148 c 9.75768,0.014 34.79672,3.33913 36.27473,4.81715 0.64735,0.64736 -6.48667,38.8851 -8.67303,46.48669 -0.95153,3.30828 -2.31046,3.67973 -8.54051,2.33446 z"
   id="d1s1"
   inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
   transform="matrix(0.26458333,0,0,0.26458333,4.9999997,48.5)"
   inkscape:label="d1s1" />
```

E crie no JavaScript crie um evento click para cada `path` que irá aplicar a classe de acordo com a cor do dataset `cor` do elemento clicado:

```
<script>
var paths = document.querySelectorAll("path");
for(var x=0; x<paths.length; x++){
   paths[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
      this.classList.add(this.dataset.cor);
   });
}
</script>
```