# Como mudar a cor de um SVG dinamicamente com props no React?

Tags: javascript, css, react, svg

Estou tentando mudar a cor de um SVG através das `props`, mas não estou conseguindo.

Meu componente `Hexagon` que no qual eu recebo a cor via `props` e verifico com um `switch`:

```
function Hexagon({ size, text, color }) {
  let hexagonColor;
  switch (color) {
    case "green2":
      hexagonColor = style.green2;
      break;
    default: {
      hexagonColor = style.green2;
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      <p className={style.hexagonText}>{text}</p>
      <img
        src={hexagon}
        alt="Hexagon"
        className={hexagonColor}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Aqui é onde eu chamo o componente e passando a cor:

```
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div >
      <div>
        <Hexagon text="Planejar" color="green2" />
        <Hexagon text="Planejar" color="green2" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Hexagon text="Planejar" color="green2" />
        <Hexagon text="Planejar" color="green2" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Aqui está o meu arquivo CSS:

```
.green2 path {
  fill: #8e18d2;
}
```

Já verifiquei e a classe realmente aparece no componente, veja na imagem abaixo

> [image: hexagon]

Comment: onde está `style`: (`style.green2`)?

Comment: Acho que um SVG que vc incorpora como <img src="....svg"> vc não consegue trocar cor assim, pelo menos não no html.... da uma olhada aqui as vezes te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286686/mudar-a-cor-de-um-svg-por-um-bot%c3%a3o/286696#286696

Comment: novic o style.green2 esta no arquivo css meu

Comment: Você pode tentar usar SVG como um componente com o [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com). O seletor `.green2 path` não vai funcionar porque a tag `img` não irá renderizar o SVG dentro dela, você pode ver pela própria print da tag que não possui nenhum `<svg>` ou `<path>` ali.

Comment: @Pedro se é um css anexo ao componente, não é só colocar o nome ?

Comment: @ Rafael Tavares nunca vi esse SVGR, vou dar uma olhada, é q eu n queria ter q instalar uma lib so pra fazer isso

Comment: @Novic n entendi muito bem o q vc disse ;-;

Comment: Vcs tinham razao pessoal, como img ele n rendenderiza nunca, tive que importar como um componente mesmo, Obrigado a todos pela ajuda. vo posta a resolução nos comentários

Comment: O svg nada mais é do que um arquivo XML, você pode setar um cor em javascript nele, exemplo: `<object class="svgClass" type="image/svg+xml" data="image.svg"></object>` -> `document.querySelector(".svgClass").getSVGDocument().getElementById("svgInternalID").setAttribute("fill", "red")`

Comment: [Veja esse exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872947/changing-svg-image-color-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver apenas importante o svg como um componente, pois a img nao renderiza o svg na tela, fiz da seguinte forma

```
import { ReactComponent as HexagonSVG } from "./hexagon.svg";
```

Logo abaixo, foi apenas usar ele como um componente mesmo, dessa maneira

```
<HexagonSVG
        className={`${style.hexagon} ${hexagonColor} ${hexagonSize}`}
 />
```