# Icones iguais aos do boostrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar um ícone meu, colocar na página, porém se quiser mudar a cor ou tamanho do ícone, eu puder fazer isso...

Por exemplo, no hover de um link, ele  mudar de cor.

att,

Comment: Se chama Font Awesome

Comment: Da pra fazer na mão só com CSS de forma simples até, mas não vai funcionar a troca de cor no IE e Edge... Se vc quiser eu faço um modelo.

Answer (score 1):

Se for sobre os ícones do [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/), você pode colocar na página qualquer ícone do [Glyphicons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons), disponíveis no site, sendo este apenas um `<span>` com as classes que faz a mudança visual.

Para toda mudança de cor ou tamanho, pode-se utilizar o `:hover` diretamente no css, em qualquer classe, id ou tag. Sempre que o mouse passar por cima do elemento, este bloco irá ativar.

Para mudar a cor do ícone, apenas utilize a propriedade `color` dentro do `:hover`.

Para mudar o tamanho, há mais de uma maneira de fazer. Eu estou disponibilizando um exemplo com `transform: scale(n)`. Verifique abaixo se é isto que está procurando (passe o mouse sobre o ícone):

```css
.glyphicon:hover {
  color: blue;
  transform: scale(2);
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
    Enter a valid email address
</div>
```

Comment: Sim, do Bootstrap eu sei...

Quero fazer igual, mas com os meus ícones... como posso fazer?

Comment: Desculpa não entendi, como assim seus ícones? Você fez algum em SVG ou algo assim? De qualquer forma, consegue tentar com o css que passei acima, aplicando para o seu caso?

Comment: Para isso você precisa de um arquivo de fonte customizado, onde cada letra é um icone monocromático.

Comment: Eu fiz os ícones em SVG... e quero utiliza-los da mesma forma que utilizo os ícones do Bootstrap...
Mesma técnica

Comment: Creio que esta resposta te ajudará https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46582/mudar-cor-do-svg-no-hover